# neo4jrestclient - query get id

Tags: neo4j, neo4jrestclient

I am using the neo4jrestclient library.

```
from neo4jrestclient.client import GraphDatabase
from neo4jrestclient import client
from neo4jrestclient import query
gdb = GraphDatabase("http://localhost:7474/db/data/")
q = """MATCH n RETURN n;"""
result = gdb.query(q=q)
print(result[0])
```

When I am executing the query "MATCH n RETURN n, the output is:

```
[{
'all_relationships': 'http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/1131/relationships/all', 
'all_typed_relationships': 'http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/1131/relationships/all/{-list|&|types}', 
'self': 'http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/1131', 
'labels': 'http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/1131/labels', 
'properties': 'http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/1131/properties', 
'create_relationship': 'http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/1131/relationships',
'outgoing_relationships': 'http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/1131/relationships/out', 
'data': {
  'title': 'title', 
  'name': 'Poludnie'
}, 
'incoming_typed_relationships': 'http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/1131/relationships/in/{-list|&|types}', 
'property': 'http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/1131/properties/{key}', 
'paged_traverse': 'http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/1131/paged/traverse/{returnType}{?pageSize,leaseTime}', 
'incoming_relationships': 'http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/1131/relationships/in', 
'outgoing_typed_relationships': 'http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/1131/relationships/out/{-list|&|types}', 
'traverse': 'http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/1131/traverse/{returnType}'}]
```

I see that the node’s id = 1131. The question is: can I obtain this id in raw forms without those links? I would like to have only the id together with the value of the ‘data’ field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Cypher, that could be expressed like this:

```
MATCH (n) RETURN {id: ID(n), name: n.name, title: n.title} as city
```

In the response, the `data` hash will contain an array and each element's `row` key will contain this data accessible using their given keys.

Answer (score 1):

To get "just the id and data, change your query to:

```
MATCH (n) RETURN id(n), n.data
```

See if that is satisfactory.